# Tiptap editing pasted content in editor problem

Tags: tiptap

I am using Tiptap Editor with vue3 in my project  , every things seems working fine, but once i copy article from  website or any text from outside Tiptap and past it in the editor , the content is past but when i am trying to edit , directly remove the pasted content and turn to empty

Comment: Do you mean the content is pasted correctly in Tiptap editor but when you start editing the whole content gets removed and you end with an empty editor document? Can you please share a little bit more details, share a working demo if you can...

Comment: Yes, when paste the content for example from any website it is pasted with all formats , also all formats has been implemented in the editor, i mean all the articles formats already implemented in Tiptap  , but once start for example change selected text font size, directly remove all content

Comment: Actually , i am developing multiple  own extensions for different porpoises ( for example Table of Content, and another functionalities  ), does that effect the the paste options in tiptap

Comment: If extensions with the schema that you want to support are in place then I'm not sure what could be the issue here. It could be worthwhile to check what's really pasted in your editor by creating a global plugin with `handlePaste` prop in it like [this](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/develop/packages/extension-code-block/src/code-block.ts#L242). You can register the plugin on the editor object like this - `editor.registerPlugin(pasteContentPlugin())`.